# IE does not read <script> tag, but after refresh works fine

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weird bug that is present only in IE (7/8/9/9CV).
FF and Chrome do not have this issue.

I have a pretty big, complex page. In the bottom of the page I have two pieces of JavaScript code right one after another. The first one has no problems, but the second one for some reason is being displayed as a text when I load the page first time. If I just refresh the page without doing anything else - everything works and looks just fine.

Two pieces of JS being generated on a server from two different pagelets so I cannot put them together into one script tag. The first piece of JavaScript code is nothing more but a call to the same function couple of times with different parameters, and the second script is just a declaration of a JSON like object that is being consumed by another function that is defined earlier on the page.

So the page code looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
<title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
//Some javascript that executes perfectly fine every time and is nothing more but just couple of calls to some function
someFunction("param1");
someFunction("param2");
someFunction("param3");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myObject = {"success":[{"header":"Form successfully submitted","messages":["Some message 1"]}]};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when a form submitting happens I take this object and use it to display a message on the page. But instead, when user submits the form and it opens the page for the first time, I see this in the bottom of the page:

```
var myObject= {"success":[{"header":"Form successfully submitted","messages":["Some message 1"]}]};
```

But when I refresh the page - I do not see that code, but instead I see the message being displayed with values from this object.

When I open the "developer tools" and navigate to the HTML tab, I see that my  tag for the second JS piece is shown as commented out!

```
<!-- sctipt ... -->
```

But if I refresh the page - it works fine, and in HTML tab of the developer tools it actually shown as a script node that I can expand and see the Javascript code.

Does anyone know what is going on here?!?! This issue has been bugging me for couple of days now!

Comment: Changed <script type="text/javascipt"> to <script type="text/javascript">
Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Here is the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/jnMz6](http://jsfiddle.net/jnMz6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an answer to this problem. Well, more of a work around I guess, as this is not something I expected but it works.

Basically, if you put anything between the two script elements - IE wokrs fine!
So what I did was - I put br tag in between and it now works fine. I have no idea why. Perhaps some weird bug in IE rendering engine.

The end result looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Some javascript that executes perfectly fine every time and is nothing more but just couple of calls to some function
someFunction("param1");
someFunction("param2");
someFunction("param3");
</script>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myObject = {"success":[{"header":"Form successfully submitted","messages":["Some message 1"]}]};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should replace

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

**EDIT :**

HTML isn't XHTML. Don't wrap your scripts inside CDATA. Your script elements should be simply like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var t0_date = new Date();
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry guys, its my typing skill, I misspelled it here, but in the real code I have it as 
<script type="text/javascript">
May bad... :(

Comment: Your pseudo code is too vague and generic. Can you build a minimal example demonstrating your problem ? For example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I know :( But the problem is that this page is on intranet, so no outside excess and even if I copy the page source as is (right mouse click > view source > Ctrl+A Ctrl+C) into a local file and run it - I never get this issue! Even though I can reproduce it 100% of times running the actual site.

Comment: Why are scripts inside <![CDATA[ */ ?

Comment: Well, this resulting HTML is a product of multiple pagelets written by multiple teams. I am assuming you are asking about the JS code that starts on line 8? It's written by another team, and I am just guessing here that they are probably trying to make sure this thing does not puke on users with old browsers.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why 

<script>var bccMessages = {"success":[{"header":"Form successfully submitted","messages":["Thank you for contacting us. A team member will follow up with you as soon as possible regarding your question or issue."]}]}</script>

code in the bottom of the page is displayed the first time I load the page

Comment: With or without CDATA - the last <script> always works fine when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Change both these:

```
<script type="text/javascipt">
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Sorry guys, its my typing skill, I misspelled it here, but in the real code I have it as <script type="text/javascript">
May bad... :(

Comment: @Pinny: That's why you should paste code from your actual code. It's really hard to find an error in the code that you are using by looking at code that you are not using...

Comment: I actually put that in my other comment, but I alos just updated my original post with the  [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jnMz6)